# how to edit the command when copy into conque

Tags: insert-mode, plugin-conque

I am using conque plugin in Vim.

When I copy some content into conque, it seems only possible to edit at the end of the command. What I wish to do is to copy something into conque and change a little bit in the middle of the command (use input mode) and execute the whole command.

After a lot of search I am still lost in doing so.

Does anybody know the trick?

Thx!

Comment: you know, that Vim 8.1 comes with a built-in terminal feature?

Comment: You should be able to do this simply by pressing `<Esc>` to enter normal mode and then moving/editing using regular Vim commands. Does this not work for you?